# python 3 convert list slice into string

Tags: python-3.4

I have a list with numbers
['1111', '1112', '1113', '1114', '1115']

and need to pull one slice and convert to string
Im using

```
str(list[0:1])
```

but that outputs ['1111'] when I only need the numbers

There is some info on the site regarding .join but I've only found posts talking about the entire list not just one piece of it.
Ive also tried using the .strip command but cant seem to get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is

```
list[0]
```

what you're looking for?

Comment: Lol thanks I didnt realize that calling it that way would remove the unnecessary characters!  
Too EZ

Answer (score 2):

A slice of a list *is* a list, thus you can join a slice just the same way as you would join a list.

```
>>> lst = ['1111', '1112', '1113', '1114', '1115']
>>> ''.join(lst[0:1])
'1111'
```

Note that when using slice-notation, the `to` index is exclusive, thus the slice `[0:1]` has just the zeroth element. In case you wanted the zeroth and first element, use `[0:2]`:

```
>>> ''.join(lst[0:2])
'11111112'
```

Of course, if you really just want one element from the list, there's no need for a slice (and for `join`); just use the index:

```
>>> lst[0]
'1111'
```